# Calculate the percentage difference between two files in Linux

Tags: linux, compare, diff

I have 4 files created today and four files created yesterday and they are saving in the same directory, want to compare four files created yesterday with four files created today and identify the difference in percentage.

Example as follows

```
ls -ltr

aa.072318
cc.072318
ee.072318
gg.072318
aa.072418
cc.072418
ee.072418
gg.072418
```

I should compare `aa.072318` with `aa.072418` and should identify the difference in percentage. Similarly for rest of the three files.

Comment: you can use diffstat like this topic explain :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159517/how-can-i-get-difference-ratio-using-diff-or-other-command

Comment: Maybe `comm` provides what you want.